# Como tratar um erro dentro de uma classe qualquer em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, exceção, syntax-error

Se faço algo como:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

print(Foo().python)

**OUTPUT:**
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'python'
```

Como posso tratar essa exceção dentro de minha classe, ao invés de tratar fora dela, por exemplo:

```
class Foo(object):
    def any_except_method():
        return 'default_value'

print(Foo().python)

**OUTPUT:**
'default_value'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer lidar com um `AttributeError` levantado por *qualquer* acesso a um atributo inexistente da sua classe, implemente o método especial `__getattr__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return 'default_value'

Foo().python  # output: 'default_value'
```

Mais informações na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado @jfaccioni!